# How to align widget in center and end in row without use of stack

Tags: flutter, layout, row

How to do like this

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZBdB.png)

code

```
        Row(
              children: [
                SizedBox(width: 33.w),
                Text(
                  StringRes.getStart,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                    color: AppColors.backgroundColor,
                    fontSize: 13.sp,
                  ),
                ),
                Spacer(),
                Icon(
                  Icons.arrow_forward,
                  color: AppColors.backgroundColor,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 3.w,
                ),
              ],
            ),
```

i get diffrent diffrent spacing in diffrent device
like this [image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpiNZ.png)
[image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKqFo.png)

Comment: and whats wrong with `Stack` widget?

Answer (score -1):

I assume what you are looking for is something like this:

```
Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
  child: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
    children: const [
      SizedBox(width: 20),
      Text('Get started'),
      SizedBox(
        width: 20,
        child: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

In this example, the Text widget is centered by having equally large SizedBox widgets on both sides of it and by telling the Row widget to use *MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween*. The padding around the Row contents is achieved with the Padding widget, so that it does not interfere with the content alignment.

I hope this helps you.